# Wondering whats in this script causing it not to work in the new jquery update

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a link to a fiddle I was looking at which does exactly what i'm looking for:

https://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/

Upon attempting to apply this for my own purposes I realized that it was not working at all. I came to the conclusion that it was the version I was using causing it not to work..

Not really a javascript/ jquery buff so I was wondering what precisely in this script causing it to not work with jquery 3.0.0-rc1 but instead with the older version jquery 1.10.2

```
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Comment: I see the script working with both versions mentioned above,, tried it in the same fiddle

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: Oh that's interesting the only difference is I was attempting to use the cdn found here instead of swapping it out in fiddle ttps://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js